# How to get rid of supertest's output when testing express applications?

Tags: express, supertest, superagent

I'm building an Express.js API and I'm using mocha and supertest for testing.

However, take a look at this:

```
  root path
GET / 200 5.789 ms - 19
    ✓ returns 200 status code 
GET / 200 0.787 ms - 19
    ✓ returns json mime type 
GET / 200 0.382 ms - 19
    ✓ contains the package version
```

I want to get rid of the GET / 200 log so it can look like this:

```
  root path
    ✓ returns 200 status code
    ✓ returns json mime type
    ✓ contains the package version
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't thing that output is being generated by supertest. Are you using logger middleware in your express app (e.g. `morgan’)? If so can you share the code where you initialize it?

Answer (score 2):

[Solved] The output was generated from morgan logger.

The solution was to wrap the middleware like this:

`if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(logger('dev'));
}`